# Node.js error when sending request from react (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS )

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, react-redux

After making request to the server, am getting net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS. This was working earlier, now the App cant make any request to the server.

Though the API's are working when tested with Postman.

```
This is the action that makes the request to the server
//Login User
export const login = (email, password) => async (dispatch) => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  };

  const body = JSON.stringify({ email, password });
  console.log(email, password);                      //This is where the run time stops and catch error
  try {
    const res = await axios.post(authLogin, body, config);
    console.log(res);
    dispatch({
      type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
      payload: res.data,
    });
    dispatch(loadUser());
  } catch (err) {
    const errors = err.response.data.errors;

    if (errors) {
      errors.forEach((error) => dispatch(setAlert(error.msg, "danger")));
    }

    dispatch({
      type: LOGIN_FAIL,
    });
  }
};
```

This is the controller for the API that's been called

```
// @route POST api/auth/login
// @desc Login user and return JWT token
// @access Public
const loginUser = async (req, res) => {
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
  }
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    const user = await User.findOne({ email });

    if (!user)
      return res.status(401).json({
        errors: [
          {
            msg:
              "The email address " +
              email +
              " is not associated with any account. Double-check your email address and try again.",
          },
        ],
      });

    //validate password
    if (!user.comparePassword(password))
      return res
        .status(401)
        .json({ errors: [{ msg: "Invalid email or password" }] });

    // Make sure the user has been verified
    if (!user.isVerified)
      return res.status(401).json({
        errors: [
          {
            type: "not-verified",
            message: "Your account has not been verified.",
          },
        ],
      });

    // Login successful, write token, and send back user
    res.status(200).json({ token: user.generateJWT() });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
    res
      .status(500)
      .json({ errors: [{ msg: "Server unavailable, try again latter" }] });
  }
};
```

This is a react, node.js, mongoDB and Redux project. Have not experience this before.

Kindly help if you have any idea what i did wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. It turns out that the SSL-VPN i was using on my machine caused the issue. All the APIs started working immediately i disconnected the VPN.